# Why does my object remain gray in the 3D View after changing its 'Base Color'?

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I want to create a **radioactive torus**. First I think I need to change/set a color. I've created a torus and then (in material properties) a changed in Edit mode to green (see the snippet below).

I've also changed **Emission** to RGB green. Not only that the emission doesn't work, even the change color doesn't work: it's not green but still gray.

What's wrong with my Torus?

[image]

**EDIT** for **solid mode**

[image]

Comment: I think you can't see the material in Solid mode, you need to switch to Render mode, if you want to change the color displayed for this object in Solid mode, go in the Material tab and Viewport Display > Color

Comment: @moonboots I have indeed found the **Viewport Display**. But it cannot be changed it , it changes back to white color whenever I change it to green one. Also I cannot find the **solid and render modes** at all in my opened Workspace. Everything (both the cube and torus) is still **gray** :-(

Comment: the Solid and Render mode are on the top right of your 3D View window (small sphere icons), you mean you can't activate them?

Comment: @moonboots WIth your advice I've found the solid mode. However, both objects (the torus and cube) look still gray though **Viewport Display** is really green. PLEASE SEE MY EDIT FOR SOLID MODE in my OQ. What shall I do now? I'm a complete beginner to Blender! Thank you.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots That's a good thing this sharing of blend files! Here it is:  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=w9l1LYla" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/w9l1LYla/)

Comment: @moonboots How can I delete them ?

Comment: delete only the first one, the little minus button on the right of the materials list

Comment: @moonboots Could you please send to me some **radioactive donut** .blend file to my email: (pax0@seznam.cz)?

Comment: sorry I don't know what radioactive donut means ah ah

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 materials in your material list, the one you've assigned is blank, you need to assign the other one (or simply delete the first one):

[image]

Comment: I have created a new file .blend because I do not know how can I delete one material. Now the color works, but the **Emission** doesn't: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=PeSKgd9G" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PeSKgd9G/) It should look radioactive like!

Comment: It seems to work fine in Cycles, I can't use Eevee on my computer, maybe someone will find the answer   ;)   maybe try some beginner Blender tutorials to learn the basics because you seem a bit lost for the moment

Comment: The point was that I should have checked the **material preview** on the top right side and it works fine now! Thank you.